# Cant execute SQL query , with Convert(Date,GetDate()) , C# WinForms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to execute this query

```
"INSERT INTO Orders Values (" + OrderId.Text + ',' + IDCustTextBox.Text + ',' + CustName.Text + ",SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))"
```

Comment: Warning - your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Don't concatenate SQL - use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Comment: Also - what does "can't" mean? What **is** happening? What errors/exceptions are you getting? What is the structure of the `Orders` table? What is the SQL the you build look like?

Comment: I know but this is a SCHOOL PROJECT so no one will try to SQLI my project DONT WORRY ABOUT IT ! just help me to solve this problem please !!

the error i get is  1: worng syntex near the word select . 2:worng syntex near the word ')'.

OrderId is Nvchar 
IdCust is Nvchar
CustName is Nvchar 
DateOfOrder is Date

Comment: I cannot guess that this is a SCHOOL PROJECT, as you DIDN'T SPECIFY THAT IN YOUR QUESTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `INSERT INTO ...VALUES`, you don't need a `SELECT`. You will use:

```
"INSERT INTO Orders 
 Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "','" + IDCustTextBox.Text + "','" + CustName.Text + "',GETDATE())"
```

By the way, you do not need to convert `GETDATE()` to a date because it is already a date.

Comment: Yea thanks i know it now i dont need use select , thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 5):

To fix the query directly, *first*, you have mistmatched single quote. *second*, you can directly pass `GETDATE()` int the value,

```
string _insert = "INSERT INTO Orders Values ('" + OrderId.Text + "','" + IDCustTextBox.Text + "','" + CustName.Text + "',GETDATE())"
```

***Your sql statement is very weak***. You should parameterized the value to avoid [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Assuming you are using `SQL Server`

```
string connStr = "connection string here";
string insertStatement = @"INSERT INTO Orders 
            Values (@ordID, @custID, @custName, GETDATE())";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = insertStatement;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordID", OrderId.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", IDCustTextBox.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custName", CustName.Text);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // ex.ToString()
            // don't hide it
        }
    }
}
```

To improve:

- use `Command` and `Parameter` to avoid from `SQL Injection`
- use `Command` and `Parameter` to avoid from `SQL Injection` -- `:D`
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle exception
- use `using` statement to properly dispose object

Comment: Works ! Thank you i didnt saw i miss that quote

And as is say this is a school project , no one care if i got SQLI , in the future i will use parameterized

Answer (score 0):

Cant you Modify Your table with DEFAULT GETDATE()?? then You dont want to insert separately.
 eg:
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ProductName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
OrderDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)